# Python: Calculate score based on weights in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe.

[image]

Here is the code for the column 'final_score':

```
weights = [0.3,0.1,0.1,0.5]
df.mul(weights).sum(axis=1)
```

As you can see, I am trying to set weights and multiply each value to get a score (listed in final_score). However there are some values that are None (NaN). My question is how do I change the weights so that the weights weigh more in other columns when an instance(s) of None is shown.

For example, in row2 all the values are present therefore the weights that I have assigned are calculating as accordingly.
In rows 0 and 1, how can I shift the weights such that there is no weight City_score and the weight is instead shifted to the other three columns (ex. [0.3,0,0.1,0.6])

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace all `NaN` values with `0` and so when the weight is applied to that cell it will automatically become 0 (i.e. the weight will proportionally shift to the other columns).

There is a method in Pandas to do this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: I just tried this but I don't see the weights shifting proportionally to the other columns as you mentioned

Comment: You won't actually see the weight numbers change, but mathematically speaking if you switch NaN for 0, then it is the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `df.fillna()`:

```
df.fillna(0).mul(weights).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Yup i just tried this however it doesn't shift the weights of the NaN to the other columns